# How to display a text in gridview "No Records Found" when there is no record

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have iframe where I have several charts and gridviews where the charts and gridviews are fetching data from database.when records found no issue but for some users don't have records for one of gridviews where I have to display a message "No records found".

kindly suggest me on this.
I tried the below code which displays a message but it displays in small box,but I need to display inside the gridview.

```
   <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
  <EmptyDataTemplate>No records Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Here I am not showing grid header,but i have to!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Set `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` property on the GridView to `true`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx

But you still have to DataBind the gridview.  This code snippet worked for me:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found">
    <Columns>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="Name" headertext="Name"/>
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 5):

try setting  `emptydatatext` and  `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty`

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView" 
        datasourceid="DataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        emptydatatext="No data in the data source."
        runat="server"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
      </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I am using for gridview for no records found is that,when there are no records in database then I clear all the rows in grid and add a new row in the grid as a text no records found,or you can create a function for no result found and then use that in bind function of gridview. When there are no records you can call that function.

Answer (score 0):

For those still using ASP.net 2 or 3.5, the `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` property does not exist. To get around this, just simply use the `EmptyDataText="..."` property and make the gridview visible only when data was found (in code behind).